# Work e-mail edit/delete of a user in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

I Want to delete a particular email address using REST API for a user as the owner have left the org and the email is bouncing with delivery failed error message.

Cant delete entire user as used in workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to disable or delete a mailbox for a user.

Disable or delete a mailbox in Exchange Server for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/disconnected-mailboxes/disable-or-delete-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019